# Error Generate on contact view page constant-contact-api

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-4.0

Error Generate on contact view page.

Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments in /home/exempar2000/public_html/wp-content/plugins/constant-contact-api/admin/contacts.php on line 427

```
<h3><?php echo sprintf(__('Contact Details (%sEdit%s)', '<a href="'.add_query_arg('edit', true) .'">', '</a>'), 'constant-contact-api'); ?></h3>
```

[constant contact api plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/constant-contact-api/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h3><?php echo sprintf('Contact Details (%sEdit%s)', '<a href="'.add_query_arg('edit', true) .'">', '</a>', 'constant-contact-api'); ?></h3>
```